# How to read json file and after a button click write to DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

The html file:

```
<p>Click the button below, to load the speaker bio details</p>
<button id="loadLess">Load Prev name</button>
<button id="loadMore">Load Next Name</button>
<div id="update"></div>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

The js file

```
let i = 0;

document.getElementById("loadMore").addEventListener("click", changeColor(json));

function changeColor(json) {
    // window.alert(evt.currentTarget.myParam);
    console.log("this");
    console.log("thist" + json[1].name);
    i = i + 1
    document.getElementById('update').innerText = json[1].name;
}

document.getElementById("loadLess").addEventListener("click", changeKolor(json));

function changeKolor(json) {
    i = i - 1;
    // window.alert(evt.currentTarget.myParam);
    document.getElementById('update').innerText = json[1].name;
}

window.onload = function () {
    fetch("data.json")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json));


};
```

The json file

```
[
  {
    "name":"Barot Bellingham name1",
    "shortname":"Barot_Bellingham",
  },
  {
    "name": "2222 name2",
    "shortname": "2",

  },

  {
    "name": "33 name3",
    "shortname": "33",

  }
]
```

It is definitely a DOM error, that I can't fix.
I can read the JSON, but I can't write it to the HTML DOM.
If a user clicks the next button it should jump to the next name, and if clicks the previous name it should jump to the next name and so on.

Comment: Where is `json` defined in the global scope?

Comment: `...addEventListener("click", changeColor(json))` etc wont work

Comment: @sinanspd how to define json in global scope?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues.

**addEventListener**

The `addEventListener` binds an event to a function. The way you implemented it, you already execute `changeColor(json)` to define that function, which won't work.

use this:

```
  document.getElementById("loadMore").addEventListener("click", function() { changeColor(json); });
  
  ...
  
  document.getElementById("loadLess").addEventListener("click", function() { changeKolor(json);} );
```

**wrong index**

inside `changeColor(...)` and changeKolor`(...)` you don't use the current index but always use 1.
change `json[1]` to `json[i]` to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

**I fixed it, but I still get that error:**

```
index.js:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: json is not defined.
```

The `.then(json => console.log(json));` write out the json array properly to the console.

**I managed to read the json file, but I can't pass to the  `changeColor(json);` function.**
It's is definitely because of onload or something like that.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  fetch("data.json")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));



};

document.getElementById("loadLess").addEventListener("click", function() {
  changeColor(json);
});

function changeColor(json) {
  // window.alert(evt.currentTarget.myParam);
  console.log("ez");
  console.log("ezaz" + json[1].name);
  document.getElementById('update').innerText = "aaa";
}

document.getElementById("loadMore").addEventListener("click", function() {
  changeKolor(json);
});

function changeKolor(json) {
  // window.alert(evt.currentTarget.myParam);
  document.getElementById('update').innerText = "less";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Click the button below, to load the speaker bio details</p>
  <button id="loadLess">Load Lesser</button>
  <button id="loadMore">Load Morer</button>
  <div id="update"></div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @sinanspd how to define json in global scope?